# In R, Join based on variables holding columns on which to join

Tags: r

Within R, I need to be able to take an existing dataframe and a "matrix" of columns to determine whether a specific case applies.  This will be easier to explain with example data.

Existing dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  FirstName = c("Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel", "Daniel"),
  LastName = c("White",   "White",    "Adams",    "Adams",    "Andrews",  "Andrews",  "Thomas",   "Thomas", "Brown", "Brown"),
  City = c("Phoenix", "MESA", "Denver",   "Albany",   "Washington",   "Washington",   "Tampa", "Taos",    "Orlando", NA),
  State = c("AZ", "AZ",   "CO",   "NY",   "DC",   "VA",   "FL",   "NM",   "FL", NA),
  Group1 = c("ABC", "ABC", "XWZ", "XWZ", "LMN", "LMN", "XWZ", "MMM", NA, NA),
  Group2 = c("D001", "D001", "A444", "A444", "M555", "M555", "E333", "F222", "Q777", "Q777"),
  Group3 = c("FORT", "FORT", "SETS", "SETS", "SETS", "SETS", "FORT", "FORT", "SETS", "SETS")
  )
```

Matrix of which columns should be used to determine the result:

```
ID_Matrix <- data.frame(
  PrimaryKeyField = c("LastName", "LastName", "Group1", "Group1"),
  PrimaryMatchData = c("White", "Adams", "XWZ", "LMN"),
  SecondaryKeyField = c("State", "Group3", "", ""),
  SecondaryMatchData = c("AZ", "SETS","",""),
  Result = c("Red", "Blue", "Red", "Green")
)
```

The ID_Matrix would look like this:

```
ID_Matrix
  PrimaryKeyField PrimaryMatchData SecondaryKeyField SecondaryMatchData Result
1        LastName            White             State                 AZ    Red
2        LastName            Adams            Group3               SETS   Blue
3          Group1              XWZ                                         Red
4          Group3              LMN                                       Green
```

Essentially the ID_Matrix table identifies which columns should be used to identify the result.  So, in the sample data above, if the "Last Name" column (the PrimaryKeyField) in the df is "White" (the PrimaryMatchData) and the "State" column (SecondaryKeyField) is "AZ" (SecondaryMatchData), then the result is "Red".

Up to this point I have used multiple joins changing the join_by to match the specific circumstances.  Something like the following:

```
SingleJoin_OnGroup1 <- df |> 
  inner_join(
    ID_Matrix[,c("PrimaryMatchData", "Result")],
    by = join_by(Group1 == PrimaryMatchData)
)

DoubleJoin_OnLName_State <- df |> 
  inner_join(
    ID_Matrix[,c("PrimaryMatchData", "SecondaryMatchData", "Result")],
    by = join_by(LastName == PrimaryMatchData, 
                 State == SecondaryMatchData
                 )
)

df_out <- bind_rows(SingleJoin_OnGroup1, DoubleJoin_OnLName_State)
```

... but there are other issues with that and I would rather use the ID_Matrix directly to automatically join/match using whatever columns are needed at the time to determine the results. I would prefer a solution using the tidyverse realm of solutions, if possible, but beggars can't be choosers.

I feel like this should be solved through using reduce or map but I can't get it to work with a join/merge or a simpler case_ option.

**June 18 Update** - adding expected results:

```
   FirstName LastName       City State Group1 Group2 Group3 Result
1     Daniel    White    Phoenix    AZ    ABC   D001   FORT    Red
2     Daniel    White       MESA    AZ    ABC   D001   FORT    Red
3     Daniel    Adams     Denver    CO    XWZ   A444   SETS   Blue
4     Daniel    Adams     Albany    NY    XWZ   A444   SETS   Blue
5     Daniel  Andrews Washington    DC    LMN   M555   SETS   Green
6     Daniel  Andrews Washington    VA    LMN   M555   SETS   Green
7     Daniel   Thomas      Tampa    FL    XWZ   E333   FORT   Red
8     Daniel   Thomas       Taos    NM    MMM   F222   FORT   <NA>
9     Daniel    Brown    Orlando    FL   <NA>   Q777   SETS   <NA>
10    Daniel    Brown       <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   Q777   SETS   <NA>
```

I also didn't point out another feature that this sample data shows - an earlier rule in the ID_Matrix overrides a later rule (e.g. - the second rule where LastName is "Adams" and Group3 is "SETS" overrides the later Group1 is "XWZ" and so the 3rd and 4th row result is Blue and not Red).  This is similar logic to case_when.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of this problem toying with me, the logic finally came in a way that both made sense to me and allowed for expansion later. Here is what I ended up with.

Altering the ID_Matrix column names slightly to make the next part easier...
(NOTE: If the original data could be updated to use the "Key" format instead of "Primary, etc." then more steps in a rule could be added without changing the code and make this step unnecessary.)

```
# Change the column names to be more consistent 
ID_Matrix <- ID_Matrix |> 
  rename_with(~ gsub("Primary", "Key1", .x)) |> 
  rename_with(~ gsub("Secondary", "Key2", .x))
```

Then, lengthen so that each step of each ruleset is its own row but tie it to the original "Ruleset".

```
# Fill empty sections with NAs to be able to drop empty rule steps later,
# Add ID number to tag each different Primary/Secondary steps in ruleset, then
# Lengthen so that each step can be dealt with individually
ID_Matrix_Long <- ID_Matrix |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Key"), ~ na_if(.x, ""))) |> 
  mutate(Ruleset = row_number()) |> # ID for each Ruleset
  pivot_longer(cols = (contains("Key")),
               names_to = c("StepNo", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.*\\d)([a-zA-Z]*)",
               values_to = c("Value"),
               values_drop_na = TRUE
  ) |> 
  mutate(StepNo = parse_number(StepNo)) |> # Primary/Sec become steps 1&2
  rename(Fieldname = KeyField) |> 
  arrange(Ruleset, StepNo) |> 
  relocate(Ruleset, StepNo, Fieldname, MatchData)
```

This gives a tibble that looks like this:

```
  Ruleset StepNo Fieldname MatchData Result
    <int>  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     <chr> 
1       1      1 LastName  White     Red   
2       1      2 State     AZ        Red   
3       2      1 LastName  Adams     Blue  
4       2      2 Group3    SETS      Blue  
5       3      1 Group1    XWZ       Red   
6       4      1 Group1    LMN       Green
```

Then create the Result field in the df and loop through each ruleset comparing
each step in the ruleset and filling in empty spots. I used a for loop here out of habit but I presume it could be translated to a tidier format.

```
df$Result <- NA_character_ # Create df Result field to be filled below

# Run through each ruleset and compare against df to find which rows
# match each step
for (Rule in unique(ID_Matrix_Long$Ruleset)) {

  # Select the steps to check within each rule
  RulesBlock <- ID_Matrix_Long[ID_Matrix_Long$Ruleset == Rule,]

  # Collect rows matching the steps in this rule and store as tibble
  MatchingRows <- 
    pmap(RulesBlock, function(Fieldname, MatchType, MatchData, ...){
      df[[Fieldname]] == MatchData
  }
  ) |> 
    as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique")
  
  # Get result of all steps in the tibble above (T/F compared)
  RuleResult <- Reduce("&", MatchingRows) 
  # ID which Result rows may be filled (are empty)
  Unfilled <- is.na(df$Result) 
  
  # Calc which rules are both: 
  # - empty (available to be filled) and
  # - which match the rule
  AvailableResult <- Reduce("&", as_tibble(cbind(RuleResult, Unfilled)))
  
  # Save the winning Rule's result to current df
  df$Result[which(AvailableResult)] <- RulesBlock$Result[1] 
}
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
df
   FirstName LastName       City State Group1 Group2 Group3 Result
1     Daniel    White    Phoenix    AZ    ABC   D001   FORT    Red
2     Daniel    White       MESA    AZ    ABC   D001   FORT    Red
3     Daniel    Adams     Denver    CO    XWZ   A444   SETS   Blue
4     Daniel    Adams     Albany    NY    XWZ   A444   SETS   Blue
5     Daniel  Andrews Washington    DC    LMN   M555   SETS  Green
6     Daniel  Andrews Washington    VA    LMN   M555   SETS  Green
7     Daniel   Thomas      Tampa    FL    XWZ   E333   FORT    Red
8     Daniel   Thomas       Taos    NM    MMM   F222   FORT   <NA>
9     Daniel    Brown    Orlando    FL   <NA>   Q777   SETS   <NA>
10    Daniel    Brown       <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   Q777   SETS   <NA>
```

If there is a better/faster/cheaper way of doing this, feel free to add it.